# Overlay GLSurfaceView over the ImageView in android

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I made a layout in which ObjectRenderer is GlSurfaceView. I want to GLSurfaceView comes on the top of the imageview. I added one method setZOrderMediaOverlay to true to set top on it. But nothing happen.

Please help me to achive this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <com.object.ObjectRenderer
        android:id="@+id/three_d_object"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- ImageView for the product -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Add this code:

```
glSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.three_d_object);
glSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```